# VBA Connect to Remote Outlook

Tags: excel, outlook, namespaces, remote-access, vba

I am able to connect to Outlook on my local machine using Excel VBA, but I was unable to find any way to remote connect to an external outlook inbox using VBA. I was hoping I could do an ODBC connection or something similar.

Does this exist? If so, how would one do it? Perhaps I'm using the wrong keywords in my search.

I was able to discover NameSpace.logon but I'm thinking this is for a local inbox only, not an external shared inbox. When I entered credentials it seemed like it didn't do anything and was still pulling from my local inbox. I welcome any insight, thanks!